# How to model exclusive behavior and make it configurable

Tags: c#, .net, logic, rules

We have to present a list of options with the following rules

```
* you can select multiple items, as many as you want
* however, some of the items are mutually exclusive, i.e. selecting itemA should automatically deselects itemC ( if itemC is selected prviously )
```

this is best explained with the following list example of fules for a car

```
Gas
Diesel
Electric
BioFuel
Ethanol
```

a car can have multiple fuel types selected such as

```
biofuel and Gas 
Gas and Electric
Gas, Ethanol and Biofuel

but not 
Diesel and Gas at the same time
```

Trying to come up with some configurable logic such that the code reads the configuration and applies the rules rather than knowing about specifics esp. since there's another list which has similar constraints

Any help/pointers on how to model this behavior ?

UPDATE -

Thanks everyone for the great ideas, the simplest solution seems to define a list of Incompatible Types in a config file/table for each fuel type as follows

FuelID/FuelName/IncompatibleTypes
1/Gas/2
2/Diesel/1
3/Electric/
4/BioFuel/
5/Ethanol/
etc.

Where IncomatibleTypes is say nvarchar(50) and will store the incompatible types like so 2,5,6,... etc.

So the code will read the definitions and if an item is selected, it will read the other selected items and if it finds anything on the incomatible list, it can either display a message or simply auto deselect the other incompatible item etc.

this may be inelegant but seems the most generic solution without the code knowing anything about specific items at all, plus it can be freely extended as in reality 
* there will likely be a couple dozen max selections at best 
* if the list of incomatibilities increases the storage can be changed to say nvarchar(100) without any changes to code itself

Answer (score 4):

I would assign a "compatibility group" number to each of the values, where the number should be viewed digit by digit.

```
FuelType | CompatibilityGroup
---------|-------------------
Gas      | 2
Diesel   | 3
Electric | 123
BioFuel  | 123
Ethanol  | 123
```

`FuelType` could be a class with a property `.CompatibilityGroup` of type `String` or anything that's easy to check character for character.

So for any combination of `FuelType`s, just check if they all have a common digit/character. If the `CompatibilityGroup`s have nothing in common, they are not compatible.

E.g.

`Biofuel` and `Gas` both have the digit `2` in common, so they are compatible.

`Gas` and `Diesel` have no digit in common, so they are incompatible.

```
Boolean IsCompatible(params FuelType types[])
{
    //Finding an algorithm that finds a common character/digit should be trivial.
    return HasCommonDigit(types.Select(t => t.CompatibilityGroup));
}
```

Comment: if you change compatibility group to a flags enum, you can `return types.Any(t => t.CompatibilityGroup & this.CompatibilityGroup > 0)`

Comment: Oh, I suppose you can't do that if the configuration needs to be read from somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I would most probably write a property or function, that loads the configuration when first needed (or just load it on application load, depending on the scenario). After that I would assign a bit to every possible value (so they are represented by powers of 2), and store the rules as numbers. When checking if a combination is valid, I would just iterate through the list of items, and check, if there is a compatible number with the checked rule. The simplest case of this is if you list all acceptable combinations, and just run a .Any expression on it, and throw an exception, when nothing is found, or in reverse, you store forbidden combinations, and throw an exception, when something is found.

This approach is way faster, than using a dictionary for example. You can even implement some effective data structure for finding the correct key, if you need performance.

For example:

```
Name     | Value    
----------------------    
Gas      | 00001 = 1    
Diesel   | 00010 = 2    
Electric | 00100 = 4    
BioFuel  | 01000 = 8    
Ethanol  | 10000 = 16
```

Possible values are:

```
Combination   | Value
----------------------
Biofuel + Gas | 01001=9
Gas + Electric| 00101=5
etc.
```

When you need to check for Biofuel + Gas, you check for 9. It is found, everything is all right.
When you need to check for diesel and gas, you check for 3. It is not found, you throw an exception.

Comment: A dictionary consumes more memory than an array, for example (although well... a so difficult reality requires various arrays); but for finding-items is not slower (at all). The approach you propose might be worthy under extreme conditions (e.g., 1 million of different fuels), but does not sound recommendable in this context. Implementing your solution requires much more programming effort (is less evident, less adaptable, etc.) than the dictionary option. I do appraise efficient approaches to a problem (taking more effort) but only when required; and in this context it is not required.

Comment: In any case... +1 because it is always nice seeing this kind of algorithms :) (although by letting clear that I don't consider that this is the best approach here).

Comment: @varocarbas: this solution cannot even achieve a large number (1 million) of fuels because it relies on the types being a bitwise flag. So it will only support 32 fuels, unless the type is specified to be long, in which case it can support 64. Memory impact should always be relatively small. :)

Comment: @mao47 thanks for pointing this out. I meant the general approach, the way to face the problem: a solution required when you want to deal just with plain arrays, when optimising everything to the limit is the only goal. It remembered me my pre-.NET period, with FORTRAN :)

Comment: @varocarbas; of course, just trying to point out every detail I see.

One note to my other comment: 32 types will correspond to 32 choose 2 (496) pairs that could be stored in the array if every single pair has a value. (but it really only needs to be 248 since you can choose allowed or disallowed combinations based on which type is more frequent).

Comment: @mao47 well... Actually all what your are saying is just an assumption (and thus both your comments have the same validity) which does not have to be applicable here: this pseudocode does not provide types, you are assuming them and also the rules. Potentially, the proposed approach might actually hide a methodology capable to deal with as big datasets as required ;)

Comment: @mao47 I want to make sure that you got the idea properly: I just intended to be nice without having even looked at what you said (I read your comment from my mobile while watching TV). I do consider that it is really nice when people intend to understand each detail further (even when they are not completely right). What I don't like too much is when people focus their further-analysis on a very specific line (which is wrong or extremely wrong), without considering anything else. A priori what you said didn't make too much sense as far as you can store in binary anything you wish...

Comment: @mao47... but I said to me "OK... he is trying to see beyond; good for him". When I read your second comment, I said to me "well... he does not seem to be getting the idea, will better clarify it". But after having dealt with various persons misunderstanding things during the last days (I hope, I SERIOUSLY hope that one of these persons is not related at all with what I will explain you right now), I have preferred to let things completely and absolutely clear for the best (I don't care about being misunderstood; I am pretty used to it; but I do care about wrongly transmitted ideas)...

Comment: @mao47 ... Even by forgetting the explanation above (you don't really know the exact system which Robert is using in his pseudocode, it seems... but does not need to be); if you want to focus on bytes and as far as there is no direct assignation bytes-fuel (you have to create one completely by your own); and there is no direct assignation bytes-combinations of fuels (you might do fuel1 = 10000; fuel1 + fuel2 = 11000); there is not even any assigned operation (you can do bitwise operations, but which ones? Also you might even perform a string analysis: positions of the digits)...

Comment: ... in summary: even by considering bytes or strings following bytes-like rules, the possible combinations potentially accounted by the proposed system are close to infinite and thus you cannot even half-guess what might be the limits, possible configurations, etc. If all this was clear (or more or less clear, at least, since my second comment), sorry about these last explanations (I seriously hate to explain and overexplain) but I am in a senseless loop lately: surrounded by completely ignorant people, thinking that they know anything at all and on whom my future depend! Really horrible :)

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect to see this much comments under my answer ^^. I'll just throw in some of my toughts:
Performance-wise my solution is supposed to work better, than a dictionary, even without any optimizations. Obviously, it requires more programming effort, but then again, the requirement to be configurable requires the same programming effort on any other solution imho.
About adaptability, and evidency: I don't see why is there an obstacle in the way of adaptability, but yeah, it has to be well-documented.

Comment: If someone uses it, the inner working would be concealed, and the solution has to be understood in depht only by someone who wants to modify it later. I do believe, that something like the compatibility group solution doesn't produduce well-readable solutions (it is basically the same), the other answers I have seen are not configurable runtime (Or not without serious reflection, what won't be easy to understand).

Comment: Obviously any optimizations won't really have an impact in a scenario, when the code is run only once every hour, to check if a value-combination fits it on a small dataset, espetionally, if it is a web-application, with database access. But let's say we want to process some really big dataset, and check for errors, you will want to see some optimised solution. Also @varocarbas , thanks for pointing out, that possible values are not limited by the length an Int32 or whatever other number.

Comment: "Performance-wise my solution is supposed to work better, than a dictionary" -> by assuming that you use a "plain" array; no doubt on that (this was the main point I intended to do). This is the main advantage from plain arrays. But by understanding what performance means: arrays memory consumption is lower (what will not be relevant for small enough sets; like anything below 10000); but some (complex) actions might be performed even quickly with Dictionaries/Lists (again, for a small enough dataset), as far as the in-built functionalities are over-optimised...

Comment: ... and it is pretty unlikely that someone builds a more efficient solution from scratch by using plain arrays. Thus, your statement (even before looking at the code clarity) has to be understood as a function of the dataset size: for not-too-big datasets; the overall performance of more "advanced" collections (e.g., dictionaries, lists, etc.) is not worse than the one from arrays... and you are welcome: I thought that it was worthy highlighting that you can build up everything by your own, that you don't really need all the fancy new features of .NET (although are really nice-to-have :)).

Comment: Of course, on a not-too-big dataset there is no point in implementing something fancy, we can agree on that :)

Comment: @varocarbas: Good point. implementor could theoretically wrap identifier in some kind of other datastructure with more capacity. Int is just assumed most common scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `Dictionary` with a list of values per key. Sample code:

```
enum fuel { Diesel, Biofuel, Gas, Electric, Ethanol };
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Dictionary<fuel, List<fuel>> dict = new Dictionary<fuel,List<fuel>>(); 

    dict.Add(fuel.Biofuel, new List<fuel>{fuel.Gas, fuel.Ethanol});
    dict.Add(fuel.Gas, new List<fuel>{fuel.Biofuel, fuel.Electric, fuel.Ethanol});
    //etc.

    fuel fuel1 = fuel.Biofuel;
    fuel fuel2 = fuel.Gas;

    if (dict[fuel1].Contains(fuel2) || dict[fuel2].Contains(fuel1))
    {
        //Both fuels can be put together
    }
    else
    {
        //Please, don't mix.
    }
}
```

This approach is very flexible and can be optimised such that you don't need to add all the fuels as keys (neither all the potential values for every key). Also you don't need to use an `Enum`. The whole point of this answer is proposing a solution based on a dictionary defined by keys and list of values which only accounts for the "valid combinations".

Answer (score 2):

All the answers so far are decent approaches to the problem, but I don't *think* any of them will give you which items should be excluded when a new item is selected, other than iterating all types (to create a pair with the selected). Ideally, I would want something like

```
List<FuelType> excluded = fuel.GetExcludeTypes();
```

or

```
FuelType excl = fuel.GetExcludeTypes();
```

if FuelType is a `Flags` enum.

Therefore my solution would be something like this:

```
enum FuelType
{
    Gas = 0x0001, etc...
}
class Fuel
{
    readonly FuelType TypeId;
    readonly FuelType Exclude;
    public Fuel(FuelType type, FuelType exclude)
    {
        TypeId = type;
        Exclude = exclude;
    }
}
```

and you can create your types something like:

```
var gas = new Fuel(FuelType.Gas, FuelType.Diesel);
var diesel = new Fuel(FuelType.Diesel, FuelType.Gas | FuelType.AlsoExclude);
```

By using the flags, and storing the OR of excludable fuel types with each fuel, you are avoiding having a list of types for every fuel, or a separate list of compatibilities that you have to feed in a pair of FuelTypes to get a bool. This way you can get all types to exclude given a fuel type and no knowledge of the other types.

I still really don't like this solution because it is determining the fuel types at runtime, but it is a nice way to get semantic functionality. There might be a better way to set up the code to achieve these same results. I welcome suggestions.